# Libs to have a minimal api rest server running with routing features fully integrated with conduit

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I'd like to stream all the way in an API rest with the conduit lib using routing features etc... So far I have used scotty but I'm obliged to terminate the stream inside my api rest call instead to fully integrate conduit with it... Maybe scotty is doing it but I didn't find a way :

```
post "/requestCommand/" $ do
                   command <- jsonData
                   (liftIO $ runConduit
                           $ yield (eventStoreConnection,command)
                             .| CommandStream.persist
                             .| sinkList) >>= json
```

I have the intuition that Yesod could do it btw, I'm investigating on that :-), conduit-extra can run a TCP server but I didn't find routing features attached with it...

Do you know some libs to have a minimal api rest server running with routing features (parsing/extracting url parameters, dispatching by post/get/put etc...) which is fully integrated with conduit ?

Comment: What do you mean conduit lib using routing features ?

Comment: What's the question?